# How to edit perticular user details from collection using `meteor Js`?

Tags: meteor

I need help for how to allow user to **modify details when click on edit button**.
More about my Question:I had develop the meteorJs app  in that when user fill the form user details are insert into collection.If the user edit the form the details are not edited, here is my code please verify and give me suggestion.

```
 clientJs:
   Template.newclientinfoform.events
      ({
        'click #clientedit': function (e,t){    

        Meteor.Hcare_users.update({cid:this.cid}, { $set:{"firstname":fname}}, {multi: true} )
           }
       });
```

Comment: Why arent you using the Meteor.users-Collection? Is fname undefined? The update-call seems to be correct. Maybe you specified any deny-options?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using the standard Meteor.users collection.

Also, for a user operation, I'd assume that you don't want multiple records to be updated, so you can remove the `multi: true` part of your update statement.

However, if you don't want to use the standard Meteor.users collection, then the query looks to be correct as is although you don't need the quotes around "firstname".  So I'd recommend the following query.

```
Hcare_users.update({ cid: this.cid }, { $set: { firstname: fname } });
```

Also, you may want to take a look at the meteor docs for [allow/deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules.

For example, in order to test if this is the problem, you could put this in any server code:

```
Hcare_users.allow({
   update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
      return true;
   }
});
```

Also, make sure there are no deny rules defined that would nullify that (deny rules override allow rules).